# Meteor: Detect when last {{> template}} finishes rendering in {{#each}}

Tags: meteor, jquery-masonry, meteor-blaze

**EDIT: A general solution has been posted in answers!**

I am currently using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to position some `{{> card}}` templates.

```
{{#each searchResults}}
  {{> card}}
{{/each}}
```

`{{searchResults}}` returns `Session.get("searchResults")`, which changes upon a new search. The page then re-renders with new `{{> card}}` templates.

I am having trouble getting my masonry to fire at the right time:

```
Template.search.onRendered(function(){
  this.autorun(function(){
    var tracking = Session.get("searchResults");
    // ...masonry code here...
  })
});
```

Currently, the masonry code fires right after `Session.get("searchResults")` changes, but BEFORE the `{{> card}}` templates are rendered or exists. In effect, masonry positions zero elements, *then* the elements get rendered (and remain in the wrong position).

**Updated question: How do I call masonry when the last `{{> card}}` template is updated?** (note: I can attach onRendered to the card template, but onRendered only fires when the card is first created, not when updated)

Comment: Call the masonry code in an onRendered block. Get rid of the autorun and session.get code from the onRendered blocks too

Comment: If you want to call that code once a card has been rendered, then do the masonry call in card.onrendered

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock I tried this, but when `Session.get("searchResults")` is updated, `{{>card}}` updates but doesn't trigger onRendered (or onDestroyed). I guess that modifies my question a bit: How do I call masonry when `Session.get("searchResults")` is updated *and* the `{{>card}}` template is updated?

Comment: To simplify, how do I call masonry when `{{> card}}` is updated? *(Since an update to `Session.get("searchResults")` will cause the card to update anyways).*

Comment: Yes this seems to be a common problem. One thing you can do is to destroy the entire list and recreate it

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock I think I found a solution: add an autorun on card that reacts to `Template.currentData();`. Whenever the template data changes, the autorun is triggered. However, 20 cards = 20 autorun instances. I'm going to find a way to only have one running, then post the solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't current data do exactly the same thing as session? You'd still need to wait for rendering to happen? Also running 20 autorun probably isn't an issue. I'd try make it work before optimising. Good chance you won't notice the difference

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock It works! My theory is that calling masonry when the Session changes happens before the template's currentData gets a chance to update. Take that with a grain of salt (newbie programmer here, though some tests I've been doing seem to indicate this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General explanation:**

1. In your object array, mark last item with `lastItem` attribute set to `true`.
2. In your HTML, render a `{{> template}}` for each array object.
3. Use `onRendered` to look for a `lastItem` attribute.
4. If it exists, then the last element has been reached!

**Example with my code:**

Mark the last item in array:

```
cards[cards.length - 1].lastItem = true;
```

Add helper that returns array:

```
Template.search.helpers({
  cards: function(){
    return cards;
  }
}
```

In search template, render template for each object:

```
{{#each cards}}
    {{> card}}
{{/each}}
```

Use onRendered to detect last item.

```
Template.card.onRendered(function(){
  if(this.data.lastItem){
    //run masonry code here!
  }
});
```